# Use JavaScriptSerializer to Deserialize object when JSON is wrapped

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

Sample of JSON:

```
{
  "1":{
       "guid":"8a40135230891fa70130891ff1000009",
       "portalId":23832
      }
}
```

The code that I am using to deserialize is:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var lead = serializer.Deserialize<WebHookResponse>([json]);
```

The code that I am using with the deserialization code is:

```
public class WebHookResponse
{
  public HubspotRecord Record { get; set; }
}
```

The code that makes up the HubspotRecord is left out. When I run the process on json data that is not wrapped behind a "1" it works perfectly.

**Currently I am thinking my problem is that the json is wrapped in the "1". I cannot use attributes with the JavaScriptSerializer and I cannot create a root element marked as "1" because of naming conventions.**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving deserializing it do a `Dictionary<string, HubspotRecord>` or a `Dictionary<string, WebHookResponse>`. I can't say I've used the `JavaScriptSerializer` much, but I'd expect it to create an entry in the database with a key of "1" and the appropriate value. Worth a try, anyway :)

Alternatively, you might want to load it in [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) into a DOM-like structure, and just deserialize the bit you really want.

Comment: Quick answer. And a good one. 

`var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, HubspotRecord>>(result);`

Comment: Excellent !  I was having exceptions trying to use jarrays on an iOS device with Xamarin/JSON.Net.  This solution was a nice alternative.