# ASP.NET JavascriptSerializer provides unwanted array-within-array?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, javascriptserializer

*Before I start I'm pretty sure [the answer given here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333594/use-javascriptserializer-to-deserialize-object-when-json-is-wrapped/6333631#6333631)  is 90% of my answer but I just can't figure out how to apply it to my situation so I'd be grateful for any help.*

When I use **JavasriptSerializer** to serialize an array of arrays as follows :

```
string foo()
{
    int[][] JaggedArray = new int[5][];
    int i = 0;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 1, 10, 100 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 2, 20, 200 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 3, 30, 300 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 4, 40, 400 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 5, 50, 500 };
    i = i + 1;
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = js.Serialize(JaggedArray);
    return strJSON
}
```

I get something like this in response :

```
{"d":"[[1,10,100],[2,20,200],[3,30,300],[4,40,400],[5,50,500]]"}
```

---

There are times when I want ASP.NET to consume the output of this function in order that it can dynamically generate Javascript into the header of the web page like this :

```
HtmlGenericControl Include = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
Include.InnerHtml = "var myJSArr = " + foo() + ";" ;
Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);
```

In order that I end up with the following JS within my page :

```
var myJSArr = [[1,10,100],[2,20,200],[3,30,300],[4,40,400],[5,50,500]]
```

---

What's the best way to adjust either the creation of the JSON or the processing of it at time of dynamic JS creation in order that I can easily append the array of arrays onto the string 'var myJSArr' ?

---

In the hope of helping someone in future I'm going to edit this question in the light of the answers/comments provided to include some code here which proved to do what I wanted. Firstly foo needed to return an array not a string like this ...

```
string foo()
{
    int[][] JaggedArray = new int[5][];
    int i = 0;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 1, 10, 100 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 2, 20, 200 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 3, 30, 300 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 4, 40, 400 };
    i = i + 1;
    JaggedArray[i] = new int[] { 5, 50, 500 };
    i = i + 1;

    return JaggedArray
}
```

This resulted in a JSON blob that looks like this :

```
{"d":[[100,101,102],[200,201,202],[300,301,302],[400,401,402],[500,501,502]]}
```

I was then able to use the following code to the dynamic build of the JS code. I'm not all sure that the following code is the best way to do it (it seems like a hell of a lot of code for something which shouldn't be terribly complex) but it does at least work

```
Dictionary<string, int[][]> dd = js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, int[][]>>(foo());
int[][] arrASRValues = dd["d"];
List<string> lstASRValues = new List<string>(arrASRValues.Length);
foreach(int[] lstASRElement in arrASRValues)
{
    lstASRValues.Add(String.Format("[{0},{1},{2}]", lstASRElement[0], lstASRElement[1], lstASRElement[2]));
}
String strASRValues = String.Join(",", lstASRValues.ToArray());
strASRValues = "val myJSArr = [" + strASRValues + "];";
Include.InnerHtml = strASRValues;
Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);
```

Comment: That quoted output from the serializer looks suspect, the value of the "d" property is a string where it should be an array. Are you sure it isn't: `{"d":[[1,10,100],[2,20,200],[3,30,300],[4,40,400],[5,50,500]]}`? (Note that there are no quotes around the array now.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're quite right the problem was the value of "d" being a string. Just to confuse matters I thought this was the "right" answer until I thought about it a bit more ! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate the creation of the array an the JSON serialisation, so that you can serialise the data only when you need to.

The problem with the response that you get from the web service is that it has been serialised twice. First you serialise the arrays into a string, then the framework puts that string in an object and serialises that. You should just return the arrays from the web service and let the framework serialise it for you.

You only need to serialise the arrays when you put it in the script.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply - once I had read I could see what I was doing wrong. I'm going to make some edits to the question to so that others can see how it should be done. Thanks again.

Comment: @southof40: You are serialising the arrays inside an object, then you are deserialising it, then you are serialising it again manually. You only need to serialise it once if you serialise only the arrays. Change the return type of the function from `string` to `int[][]`.